# pure states on B(H) space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, we define a state $U$ on $A$ as a positive linear functional with this property:

$U(1)=\|U\|=1$.

my problem is to characterize pure states on $B(H)$ space.

show that for every pure state $U$ on $B(H)$ there is a unit vector called $x$ which $U(T)=\langle Tx,x\rangle$ for all $T$ in $B(H)$

any hint will help

Comment: It seems that ${1\over2}\langle Tx,x\rangle +{1\over2}\langle Ty,y\rangle$ for $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ is also a state. Perhaps you are after pure states.

Comment: This is not true, unless you assume your state is normal ($\sigma$-weakly continuous).